# Recognizing texts as URLs in Winforms

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

I am rendering some text in GUI and trying to recoganize the URLs. Also I need to open the URLs in browser when click events are performed. I have attached the model code snippent below. My question is how to make these texts a valid URLs and how to make them to respond to click events. And one more thing this due to some requirements I cant change the structure of the below code snnipet.

```
namespace Model
{
    public partial class ParentView : Form
    {        
        public ParentView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }
        private void ParentView_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            GraphicsState state = e.Graphics.Save();
            GraphicsRenderer renderer = new GraphicsRenderer(e.Graphics);
            renderer.RenderAsImage();
            e.Graphics.Restore(state);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Brushes.Black), 0, 0, 300, 300);
            //I believe need to do something here
        }        
    }  

public class GraphicsRenderer
{ 
    Graphics PageGraphics;
    public GraphicsRenderer(Graphics g)
    {
        PageGraphics = g;
    }

    public void RenderAsImage()
    {
        Point currentLocation = new Point(0, 0);

        PageGraphics.TranslateTransform(20, 40);
        PageGraphics.DrawString("www.google.com", new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point), Brushes.Black, currentLocation);

        PageGraphics.TranslateTransform(20, -40);
        PageGraphics.DrawString("www.stackoverflow.com", new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point), Brushes.Black, currentLocation);

        currentLocation = new Point(50, 60);
        PageGraphics.DrawString("www.stackoverflow.com", new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point), Brushes.Black, currentLocation);
    }
}    
}
```

Thanks,
Mkn

Answer (score 0):

If you're just writing text to the screen as graphics you can't make it clickable.  You'll need to position a `LinkLabel` or other clickable control at the right position to trigger the url opening in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response. I have analyzed further and found a way. Drawing rectangles over the text and finding the rectangles in mouse click events using Rectangle. Contains(MouseLeftClikLocation).

Now I am having another problem. If scale transformation is performed I could not able to get the location after restoring the graphics.

Please find the code snnipet below.

```
private void ParentView_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    GraphicsState state = e.Graphics.Save();
    GraphicsRenderer renderer = new GraphicsRenderer(e.Graphics);
    renderer.RenderAsImage();
    e.Graphics.Restore(state);
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Brushes.Black), 0, 0, 300, 300);

    //I am changing here
    float[] transformPoints = renderer.transformPoints.Elements;
    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(transformPoints[4], transformPoints[5]);
    Point currentLocation = renderer.currentLocation;
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Brushes.Black),new Rectangle(currentLocation.X,currentLocation.Y,190,30));
}
public class GraphicsRenderer
{
    Graphics PageGraphics;
    internal Matrix transformPoints = new Matrix();
    internal Point currentLocation = new Point(0, 0);

    public GraphicsRenderer(Graphics g)
    {
        PageGraphics = g;
    }

    public void RenderAsImage()
    {
        currentLocation = new Point(50, 60);
        //PageGraphics.ScaleTransform(3, 3);
        PageGraphics.DrawString("www.bing.com", new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point), Brushes.Black, currentLocation);
        transformPoints = PageGraphics.Transform;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting the transformed location using Graphics.Transfrom property. How can i get the location of the text in which scale transformation is performed.